# Is it true that $x^2-y^2=0$ iff $(x-y)(x+y)=0$

Tags: analysis, logic

since it is biconditional, what i did was see if A->B is true and B->A is true.

so for $x^2-y^2=0 \implies (x-y)(x+y) = 0$, the left hand side reduces to $x=y$. then i plugged into $(x-y)(x+y) = 0$, which gives $0(y+y) = 0$. This is true.

For $(x-y)(x+y) = 0 \implies x^2-y^2=0$, I used foil and indeed it is true.

since $A\implies B$ and $B\implies A$ is true, the statement is correct.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this trivial because $x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)(x - y)$ and obviously the equality goes both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$, I think you may have overcomplicated this issue a bit.

Also, your proof is wrong. You said that $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ simplifies to $x=y$, which is not true at all. For example, if $x=1$ and $y=-1$, then $x^2-y^2=0$, but $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

To prove that forward direction, we suppose that $x^2-y^2=0$. Factoring this as a difference of squares, we have $(x+y)(x-y)=0$, as desired.

To prove the reverse direction, we suppose that $(x+y)(x-y)=0$. Multiplying this out, we obtain $x^2 - xy + xy - y^2 = x^2 - y^2 = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Actually, OP's proof is not true, as he claims that $x^2-y^2=0$ simplifies to $x=y$, which is not true. The statement of course *is* true, but the proof is incorrect.